# Does my motherboard support M.2 2280 SSD?

Tags: ssd, motherboard

I have a B450M-HDV R4.0 ASRock and I've been using this second hand HDD that barely runs and has some clicking sounds so I was wondering if I could switch to an SSD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### I was wondering if I  could switch to an SSD

Your motherboard supports:

> 4 SATA3, 1 Ultra M.2 (PCIe Gen3 x4 & SATA3)*
>
> *Actual support may vary by CPU.

Source: [ASRock > B450M-HDV R4.0](https://www.asrock.com/mb/AMD/B450M-HDV%20R4.0/index.asp)